# Loop through first 12 files in directory and break out if file is found

Tags: bash

In Bash, what is the best way to loop through the first 12 folders in a directory in search of a file, and if the file is found then exit out of both loops.

This is my attempt so far. It doesn't:

- limit the search scope to the first 12 folders
- break out of the nested for loop when a file is found

How do I fix this?

```
#!/bin/bash

value="test.txt"
file_found = false

cd /backup/logs || exit 1
ls -1tr | head -n -12 | while read -r folder; do
   cd /backup/logs/${folder}
   ls -1tr | while read -r file; do
      if [[ ${file} == ${value} ]]; then
         file_found=true
         echo "file found in ${folder}"
         break
      fi
   done
   if [[ ${file_found} == true ]]; then
      break
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `head -n 12` to list the first 12 lines of the output, not `-n -12`: it lists all the files but the last 12.

Use `break 2` to break from nested loops of depth 2.

Use `ls -d */` to only list directories (i.e. don't show files, don't show contents of the directories).

Answer (score 3):

Use a `for` loop, not a `while` loop. You don't need a second loop; you can test directly if a file named `"$value"` exists.

```
i=0
for folder in /backup/logs/*
    if [ "$i" = 12 ]; then break; fi
    cd /backup/logs/"$folder"
    if [ -f "$value" ]; then
        echo "file found in $folder"
        break
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: Thanks for this snippet, it looks cleaner and simpler than my current implementation!